# Can we write $3.9\ \mathrm{M\Omega} \pm 5\%$ as $3.9 \pm 5\%\ \mathrm{M\Omega}$?

Tags: conventions, error-analysis, si-units, metrology

I have a doubt regarding units. Can we write $3.9\ \mathrm{M\Omega} \pm 5\%$ as $3.9 \pm 5\% \mathrm{M\Omega}$?

Comment: Conceptually, what's the difference?

Comment: @N. Steinle Are you suggesting that it's correct?

Comment: What you wrote is right if you are referring to a tolerance for example of a stock of resistors, not if you are writing a measure with an uncertainty.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going with "No" to both of the options. The standard for engineers appears to be:

$$ 3.9\,{\rm M}\Omega,\,5\%$$

and this is with good reason. Here's a chart:

[image]

When you buy a lot of 100 ohm, 10% resistors, your going find the measured values uniformly distributed (in ohms) from [90, 95] and then [105, 110], while the 5% lot is [95, 99] and [101, 105], and so on down to 0.05%, which will be *uniformly* distributed on [99.95, 100.05]. That is just how they are made.

The point is, the tolerance is not an error bar, so that the $x \pm \delta x$ notation gives a false impression of the variance of you resistance.

And, if it were an error bar, the standard deviation of a uniform distribution from [0, 1] is not $\pm \frac 1 2$, it's $\frac 1  {\sqrt{12}}$.

Comment: Engineer here. I can live with both  3.9 MΩ±5% and 3.9MΩ,5%. They convey what I need to know exactly how I expect it. But 3.9±5%MΩ is weird. The 3.9 lost its unit while the 5 suddenly has two (percent and MΩ.. which is it?).